# Why is Height Auto Respected but Width Auto not Respected on Relative Positioned Parent Element CSS

Tags: html, css

In css the position properties seem simple but in reality, there‘s tons of weird edge cases that seemingly come out of nowhere when building a layout.

One thing that I always skimmed over was when I would see `height: auto` or `width: auto`. In trying to understand this better, I came across the below code and I am hoping someone can try to explain why this happens.

The reason I am confused is if `position: absolute` is used, since `height` and `width` are both `auto` on the parent, the parent becomes `50px` x `50px`.

This doesn't happen though when the parent is relatively positioned. When the parent has `position: relative`, `height: auto` works but `width: auto` does not cause the parent to take on the width of it‘s child as I would expect. Instead with `position: relative`, the element stretches the length of the whole line.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.a {
  /*
    why is width auto not respected, but height auto takes the
    height of the child??

    if position was absolute then the height and width
    both take on the dimensions of the child
  */
  position: relative;
  background: #ff9999;
  top: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.b {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not only related to position but also to the display of the element. You can find how the width of each element is calculated here https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins

You will see a lot of categories. When your element is `position: relative` we don't care about position but we see other criteria like the fact it's a [block level element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth) and it follows the rule:

> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block

And when it's `position: absolute` we consider [different rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) and somewhere you can read:

> .. then the width is shrink-to-fit

I won't detail each case but you can read the first link to understand all the cases of width calculation. They are a lot but a quick reading will give you a clear idea on how the width and height of the elements is calculated.